# Carrots of other colors besides orange

Tags: nutrition, eye, benefits, vegetable

Are carrots other than orange good for the eyes? Do they contain any vitamin A? I'm mostly just curious about potential foodstuffs that are good for the body & I'm starting with carrots because I read a lot. If they are beneficial to the eyes or any other part of the body, could you let me know please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate in Cooking or Biology.

Comment: Could be,not sure where to put it myself @CareyGregory

Comment: @CareyGregory - Before recommending other sites, you should become more familiar with their scope. The nutritional aspects of food are off topic on Cooking, unless they relate directly to the preparation of the food.

Comment: @JohnP Understood, but that comment was posted well over a year ago.

Comment: @CareyGregory - Ah. I missed the dates. Just the "closed 9 hours ago" section. Thanks for the cleanup. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not only are carrot colors other than orange still good for beta carotene (although some do have considerably less - purple still has an orange core though) things like kale, which are not at all orange, have a lot of beta carotene.  for serving size, there is more Vit A in kale, than carrots.  Sweet potatoes are also higher.

For a very easy reference on what carious carrot colors have in them, I found this the most simplistic explanation.  You can skip a lot of the reading & just scroll down the chart. http://healthland.time.com/2013/08/20/eat-this-now-rainbow-carrots/

Overall I haven't found much that shows white carrots to be terribly nutritious but they do help your system in digestion.